# C# - Selenium, NUnit - Fixture type contains generic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, selenium, nunit

I have the following piece of code which runs fine in my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate version but in Visual studio 2015 community version gets the error

> Fixture type contains generic parameters. you must either supply Type
>   arguments or specify constructor arguments that allow NUnit to deduce
>   the Type arguments

I noticed in the community version the TWebDriver is blue in colour and black in the 2013 version. Apart from this the code looks exactly the same so I can't work out what is causing the error. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace JiraTraining
{
    [TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
    [TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
    public class BrowserTests<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver,new()
{

    [SetUp]
    public void Initalise()
    {
        GlobalDriver.driver = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TWebDriver), new object[] { EnvironmentData.driverPath }) as IWebDriver;
        GlobalDriver.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        GlobalDriver.driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(EnvironmentData.objectTimeout));
    }

    [TestCase("myUser", "myPassword")]
   public void JiraLoginTest(String userName, String password)
    {
        Keywords.LogThis("**** Running Test - " + TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name + "****");

        pgLogin loginPage = new pgLogin();
        loginPage.Login(userName,password);

    }
```

Comment: What NUnit version you're using?

Comment: Hi The versions are as below. The NUnit and selenium versions are the same in 2013 and 2015. I din't check the .Net framework on the 2015 so will need to do that tomorrow when I have access to the computer it is on

NUnit 3.4.1
Selenium Support 2.53.1
Selenium webdriver 2.53.1
.Net Framework 4.5

Comment: I tried out very similar legacy code which I originally had coded in VS 2013 and copied the class to project in VS2015. This also uses TWebDriver. Unfortunately, it does not give me any kind of error. Does the error occur in Init() for you?